# Why does the LXX verse sequence in 1 Kings 11:3-4 differ from HB MT verse sequence of 1 Kings 11:4?

Tags: masoretic-text, lxx

1 Kings 11:3-4 LXX

> <sup>**3**</sup> In time Solomon became old, and his heart was not perfect after the Lord his God, as was the heart of David his father. <sup>**4**</sup> The foreign women turned his heart after their gods.

Rick Brannan, Ken M. Penner et al., The Lexham English Septuagint, Second Edition. (Bellingham, WA: Lexham Press, 2020), 3 Kgdms 11:3–4.

1 Kings 11:4 HB MT

> For it came to pass, when Solomon was old, that his wives turned away his heart after other gods: and his heart was not perfect with the Lord his God, as was the heart of David his father.

Comment: This is another of the many thousands of places where the LXX differs from the MT.

Comment: Numbering the chapters and verses occurred in the sixteenth century.

Comment: Yet another indication that LXX is not an original inspiration (scripture) but an academic translation. The wives affected the heart and the heart was not perfect : is the logical progression and the spiritual effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, this is a matter of syntax or phraseology, possibly involving the issue of whether Solomon's imperfect heart led to his sin or vice-versa. The LXX  placed the "foreign women" phrase at the end of the thought and made it into a separate sentence. The MT placed the "foreign women" phrase in the middle of the thought used only one sentence to express the idea.

A plausible explanation is based on the logical presumption that the original Hebrew resembled the MT rather the Greek of the LXX. Keeping in mind that neither the original Hebrew nor the LXX had punctuation marks, the LXX improved the readability of the original sentence by dividing it in two, with the "foreign women" phrase at the end. At the same time the LXX clarified (whether intentionally or not) that the primary cause of Solomon's sin was that his heart was not perfect, while the MT might imply that his heart became imperfect due to his sin.

Punctuation came later, and much later after that, verse numbers were added. This resulted in modern LXX versions placing "foreign wives" in vs. 4 and the MT retaining it in vs. 3.